# Вопрос о видео фоне

Tags: javascript, html5, видео

Как сделать  для мобильный устройст видеофон ?
http://wingy.host/item/0004/0001    Вот  на первом экране есть видео при нажатии. Сайт только для мобилок.  Нужно сделать так что серый участок был фоном  это первый кадр с видео которое воспроизводится.   Для того что имеем сейчас использовался jplayer.

Comment: На мобильных устройствах нужна кнопка play

Answer (score 0):

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

function playVid() { 
    vid.play(); 
} 

function pauseVid() { 
    vid.pause(); 
}
```

```css
/* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */
#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Style the button used to pause/play the video */
#myBtn {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
 
 <video autoplay muted playsinline webkit-playsinline loop id="myVideo"> 
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
<div class="content">
<button onclick="playVid()" type="button">Play Video</button>
<button onclick="pauseVid()" type="button">Pause Video</button><br> 

</div>  

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Не работает на iphone

Comment: Добавьте атрибут к video - playsinline

Comment: @Дмитрий обновил ответ

Comment: На iphone 7 и oneplus работает.